# NPM installing to ~/.npm directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

I have to run `npm install --prefix ./ --save bootstrap jquery` for it to save in the node_modules. I expect from what I've read in tutorials and such this is not the expected behavior. When I just run `npm install --save bootstrap` it puts the files into `/home/philip/.npm` directory as `/home/philip/.npm/bootstrap`.

`npm root` gives the correct `[project]/node_modules` directory.

NPM Version: 3.10.10

Node Version: 6.10.3

OS: Ubuntu 17.04

Edit: Forgot to ask the question, how do I ensure npm install defaults to the project's node_modules directory?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because `global` [flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#global) is set to true somewhere in npm config or via an environment variable.
To check current value run: `npm config ls -l | grep global`. To change it try to add `global=false` to your `~/.npmrc` file. Also, check the value of `$NPM_CONFIG_GLOBAL`, it has higher priority than `.npmrc`.